# How to filter a Laravel parent model and all its nested child models in one place based on user info?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, design-patterns, eloquent

Imagine I have these Models : `User`, `Country`, `State`, `City`, `Library`, and we know that they have nested relationships together.
`Country` Model has many nested child Models that belong to it.
I need to filter all the data from all the child Models of `Country` based on `User`'s country of origin.

For example I have a `User` from US and I want to limit his access to only view and edit the information related to the US.
Like in `LibraryController` I need to get all the libraries that belong to US.

I can implement the logic in every Model by filtering the data using `whereHas` ( and filter the result based on country relationship ) but I want to know is there a way to do this only in the Parent ( `Country` ) Model? This way a lot of redundant code will be avoided.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can use eager loading with constraints to filter both the parent model and its nested child models in one place based on user info.

Assuming you have a parent model User and it has many nested child models Order and Invoice, you can use eager loading with constraints to filter the User and its nested Order and Invoice models as follows:

```
    $user = User::with(['orders' => function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
    // Add additional constraints as necessary
},'orders.invoices' => function ($query) use ($startDate, $endDate) {
    $query->whereBetween('created_at', [$startDate, $endDate]);
    // Add additional constraints as necessary
}])->find($userId);
```

Comment: So you mean in every child Controller I have to get the data from Parent to Child? Like in your example in both InvoiceController and OrderController I have to get data starting with User model ? Because that's exactly what I try NOT to do .